# Devemos usar a tag "javascript" em perguntas sobre "node.js"?

Tags: debate, tags, syntax-highlighting

**Devemos incluir a tag [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) em perguntas sobre [node.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)?**

Faço a pergunta porque venho percebendo recentemente que muitas perguntas sobre Node.js possuem algum trecho de código em JavaScript que acaba não recebendo o *syntax highlighting* pela ausência da tag [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Isso deve ser considerado um *problema*? Não sei se o que faço é *certo*, mas sempre que encontro alguma pergunta que se enquadra nessa situação, edito-a, adicionando a tag [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), como fiz [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/384017/como-abrir-um-servidor-local-usando-node).

Comment: Vou deixar outras pessoas responderem, mas eu acho que deveria na maioria dos casos, a não ser que seja só sobre a infra dele e não código. Pra falar a verdade pelo que vejo a imensa maioria dos casos não deve usar a tag [tag:node.js] porque é circunstancial que esteja usando ele.

Comment: Eu também acho que deve, pois uma parte delas o problema estará mesmo no javascript e não é relacionado somente ao node. Como acréscimo o syntax highlighting ajuda bastante

Answer (score 6):

É "simples", se a pergunta é sobre um script ou lib que vai executar em Node.js então provavelmente sim, terá que conter a tag [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), agora se o script que será interpretado por algum intermediário no Node.js, como TypeScript que é convertido para JavaScript, ai a pergunta tem que conter a tag TypeScript, posso presumir que nem sempre as perguntas precisarão da tag [node.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) quando o problema é o algoritimo, ainda mais se o tal problema do algorítimo é realmente algo que poderia ocorrer independe-te do ambiente (browser ou node.js)

Claro que é valido na maior parte dos casos informar o ambiente, ainda mais se a pessoa tem pouca experiencia e não consegue entender se a falha é relacionada ao algoritimo ou a alguma dependencia, ou realmente ao ambiente, até mesmo especifica o ambiente ajuda a quem vai responder sugerir soluções melhores, algo que funciona bem em browser pode ser resolvido de forma diferente e melhor em Node.js+Express, em Node.js com outros ambientes que não sejam servidores pode ser que existam soluções diferentes, colocar as tags corretas (mesmo que a pergunta não seja sua) com toda certeza ajudará nisto.

Agora uma coisa que acho totalmente errado, é localizar a pergunta com tags baseado nas respostas, a 3 anos atrás tinha uma pessoa que respondia as perguntas com soluções especificas e adicionava tags na pergunta o que acabava limitando novas respostas a serem especificas, mesmo que a pergunta desse margem para diferentes soluções, foi complicado orientar o tal usuário, pois ele estava resistente a aceitar que aquilo que fazia não era o melhor caminho para o site, felizmente ele "desistiu" depois de um tempo.

Sei que isso vai além da sua pergunta, mas para resumir o caso é que, se a pergunta "permitir" uma solução que funcione em diferentes ambientes eu pessoalmente não vejo mal algum, e se for adicionar tags, como node.js primeiramente confirme com o AP se este é o ambiente necessário para resolver o caso dele, ai acho que a sua edição pode ser saudável.